usb_service_win.cc:445: Failed to parse device interface GUID
I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to print the window using the headless mode, but when I run the script I am getting this error:

ERROR: [27916:23992:0522/164416.119:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(195)] [16:44:16.119] USB: usb_service_win.cc:445 Failed to parse device interface GUID:

If I remove the headless mode the script it's working without issues.
selenium version: 4.21.0
CODE:
import json
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState),
    "savefile.default_directory": r"C:\Test"
}

options = Options()
service = Service()

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')

Does anyone know what I need to do?
I tried to change the version of the selenium but the same issue when I'm using headless.
